# ASP.NET Web API OData batch returning HTTP 404

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing, jaydata

I'm getting started with ASP.NET Web API v2 and OData (v3). 
I've got a client made with JayData v 1.3.6

**Client Context**

```
onlinedb = new $todo.Types.ToDoContext({
    name: 'oData',
    oDataServiceHost: 'http://localhost:49375/odata'
});
```

**Server Routes**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.ContainerName = "WebAPIDataCollectorContext";
    builder.EntitySet<TodoItem>("Todo");
    config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.EnableCors();
}
```

**Request** 
OPTIONS /odata/$batch HTTP/1.1 (From Fiddler)

**Response**

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:49375/odata/$batch'.","MessageDetail":"No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost:49375/odata/$batch'"}
```

**Comments**

```
http://localhost:49375/odata/Todo (GET operation) is working fine.
```

The question is: Why is batch operation failing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch operations aren't supported by ASP.NET WebAPI OData, but you can configure it by following this article - [Introducing batch support in Web API and Web API OData](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/introducing-batch-support-in-web-api-and-web-api-odata.aspx)

Comment: I thought this line was the one that enable batch:

config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));

Thanks for the link.